# Publisher and subscriber in one ROS node error

Tags: gazebo, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I`m doing some underwater UUV Gazebo simulation and would like to use the

```
hector_pose_estimation
```

package to fuse IMU and Fluid pressure sensors input for pose estimation.

So my Pressure Sensor has `sensor_msgs/FluidPressure` but the package wants `pressure_height (geometry_msgs/PointStamped)` as input. So I created a ROS C++ node to republish sensor_msgs/FluidPressure as the geometry_msgs/PointStamped. The code compiled with no error, but when run it I got error. Firstly, this is the code

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <sensor_msgs/FluidPressure.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PointStamped.h>


double current_pressure;
double depth;
ros::Publisher pub;
geometry_msgs::PointStamped pressure_height;
void pressureCallback(const sensor_msgs::FluidPressure::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  
     current_pressure= msg->fluid_pressure;

     depth=current_pressure / (997.04 * 9.8);

     //geometry_msgs::PointStamped::ConstPtr& output;
    
     pressure_height.point.z = depth;
     //positions_pub.publish(output_msg); 

     std::cout << "Pressure: " << pressure_height << std::endl;

      //pressure_height = output.point.z;
      pub.publish(pressure_height);
       
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "pressure_republisher");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/rexrov2/pressure", 10, pressureCallback);
  ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PointStamped>("pressure_height", 100);
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

And when run it this it the ERROR:

```
[FATAL] [1633258406.824329181, 173.610000000]: ASSERTION FAILED
    file = /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/publisher.h
    line = 106
    cond = false
    message = 
[FATAL] [1633258406.826511155, 173.612000000]: Call to publish() on an invalid Publisher
[FATAL] [1633258406.826551511, 173.612000000]:
```

Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387859/publisher-and-subscriber-in-one-ros-node-error/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2021-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a C++ problem.

You have:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
...

ros::Publisher pub;

...

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ...
  ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PointStamped>("pressure_height", 100);
  ...
}
```

The `pub`  outside your `main(..)` (ie: in the global scope) is not the same `ros::Publisher` as the one you create and initialise inside `main(..)`. The latter is a new variable, which happens to have the same name (it *shadows* the `pub` in the global scope).

In your `pressureCallback(..)` you then try to use the `pub` in the global scope, which hasn't been initialised yet. This is an error, as you can't use a `ros::Publisher` which hasn't been initialised, hence the fatal error message .

You should be able to do this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ...
  pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PointStamped>("pressure_height", 100);
  ...
}
```

Having written that, the following might be easier, and still results in the conversion being performed:

```
rosrun topic_tools transform /rexrov2/pressure /pressure_height geometry_msgs/PointStamped \
  'geometry_msgs.msg.PointStamped( \
    header=m.header, \
    point=geometry_msgs.msg.Point( \
      x=0.0, \
      y=0.0, \
      z=(m.fluid_pressure / (997.04 * 9.8)) \
    )' \
   --import geometry_msgs
```

This uses `topic_tools/transform`, which avoids the need to write your own node entirely.

Note 1: this ignores the variance in the `FluidPressure` message.

Note 2: I haven't tested this, so there may be a syntax error hidden there.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1